# Можно ли сократить/упростить данный код?

Tags: python

Код простой, но занимает довольно много строк, можно ли его сократить/упростить?

```
match_date = "07.12.2022 21:45".split(".")
day = str(int(match_date[0]))
month = int(match_date[1])
match_time = str(match_date[2].split(" ")[1])

if month == 1:
    print(day + "-го " + "января в " + match_time)
if month == 2:
    print(day + "-го " + "февраля в " + match_time)
if month == 3:
    print(day + "-го " + "марта в " + match_time)
if month == 4:
    print(day + "-го " + "апреля в " + match_time)
if month == 5:
    print(day + "-го " + "мая в " + match_time)
if month == 6:
    print(day + "-го " + "июня в " + match_time)
if month == 7:
    print(day + "-го " + "июля в " + match_time)
if month == 8:
    print(day + "-го " + "августа в " + match_time)
if month == 9:
    print(day + "-го " + "сентября в " + match_time)
if month == 10:
    print(day + "-го " + "октября в " + match_time)
if month == 11:
    print(day + "-го " + "ноября в " + match_time)
if month == 12:
    print(day + "-го " + "декабря в " + match_time)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
lst = ["января", "февраля", "марта", "апреля", "мая", "июня", "июля",
       "августа", "сентября", "октября", "ноября", "декабря"]
data, time = "07.12.2022 21:45".split()
day, month, _ = data.split('.')   # day, month, year = data.split('.')

print(f'{day}-го {lst[int(month) - 1]} в {time}')
```

Answer (score 4):

Лучше словарь:

```
months = {1: "января", 2: "февраля" итд
print(day + "-го " + months[month] + match_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Странно, что никто не написал про **datetime**

```
import locale
import datetime

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'ru_RU.UTF-8')

match_date = "07.12.2022 21:45"
date_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(match_date, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")
date_string = date_object.strftime("%e-го %B в %H:%M")
print(date_string)
```